# Why isn't merge in QGIS working for me?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, qgis-3, mosaic, gdal-merge

I am attempting to merge 153 geotifs into one large geotif of the Portland area. This is what my rasters looked like before the merge: [image]
Here is a zoomed in image:[image]

This is what the raster looks like after the merge:[image]
Here is a zoomed image after the merge:[image]

Here is the console call:

`gdal_merge.bat -ot Byte -of GTiff -o D:/Desktop/483/startingover_merge.tif --optfile C:/Users/Travis/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_58647a944689450d886257b54252fa5d\mergeInputFiles.txt`

Comment: Is it possible, that the merge worked, but QGIS automatically uses a not well fitting colour range?

Answer (score 1):

<s>If you look at the console command:</s>

```
gdal_merge.bat -ot Byte -of GTiff -o D:/Desktop/483/startingover_merge.tif --optfile C:/Users/Travis/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_58647a944689450d886257b54252fa5d\mergeInputFiles.txt
```

the **-ot Byte** parameter means the bit-depth is 8-bit unsigned integer. If it's significantly different from your input, this is why the tone is so far off. You should specify the same output as your input images.

Actually, after doing a small test, I'm pretty sure it's just color stretching. The value range of the merged image is greater than all the other combined images. Try copying the style of the tile in your screenshot and pasting it to the mosaic. If it fixes the image for that particular area, it's just a matter of playing with the symbology until it looks better.